# How to debug an electron app packaged with squirrel that won't start on some computers

Tags: windows, electron, squirrel.windows

I've built an Electron app using the Squirrel packager/update manager.
I've had no issues in building the bundle, targeting Windows 64bits only.

I installed it on my Macbook pro (on a windows 7 x64 dual boot) without trouble. I tested it also on a 64 bit Surface pro 3 (Win 10), and another Win 7 PC. Everything works fine.

I published the app and got a few hundred downloads :half the people that downloaded it has it working, and for the other half it just won't start. The process spawns, then dies a second after. I tried starting it in admin, the admin dialog box won't even show. I tried running it from command line

```
myapp.exe > out.txt
```

But out is empty. How can I debug this ?

Comment: What version of Electron does your packaged app use?

Comment: electron-builder": "^3.17.1", "electron-installer-squirrel-windows": "^1.3.0", "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.0", "electron-winstaller": "^2.3.0". I cloned the electron quick start repo about 2 months ago, couole weeks before 1.0

Answer (score 3):

I was [having trouble getting the logs for a production build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140960/where-can-i-find-the-logs-for-my-electron-app-in-production) as well.

My solution was to use [electron-log](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log) to let the production app write logs to disk while debugging the problem.

You can then access the logs on windows at:
`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\<app name>\log.log`.

Add some logs in your app that will give you insights in where the app crashes.

Don't forget to remove electron-log when you're done debugging and don't need to write any logs to disk any more.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for many users by building directly on a windows 10 fresh install. 
The builds I used before were built on a windows 7. Not sure if it was that, I also have been cleaning the node modules a little bit, so maybe one of the modules I removed was the issue. Anyways, I still do not know of to debug the built exe in this kind of situation. There must be a way to get a log or something when the process kills itself